# Relationship between potential and electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

[image]

There are a number of ways to solve this problem but was interested in doing it via the formula:

$$   ∇V = -E$$

However the potential on the line due to -q is $$ \frac{-q}{4\pi\epsilon_0((0.5d)^2+y^2)}$$

whilst the potential on the line due to +q is $$ \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0((0.5d)^2+y^2)}$$

Therefore the total potential at any point on the line is zero and so we are unable to determine its gradient and electric field via this method. I am unsure why this is the case.

Comment: Two problems: First, these expressions don’t have the right dimensions to be potentials. Second, it is possible for a potential to be zero along a line but its gradient not be zero along that line, because the gradient depends on the value just *off* the line. You have to set $x$ to 0 *after* taking the gradient.

Answer (score 2):

You've only taken the $y = 0$ line, so your equations for the potential aren't "aware" of the $x$-component of the true electric field. (Also you missed the square root.) The real potential, *everywhere*, is 
$$V(x, y, z) = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left((x - d/2 )^2+y^2 + z^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{-q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left((x + d/2 )^2+y^2 + z^2\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Then $$E_x(0, y, 0) = -\nabla_x V = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}V(x, y, z)\Big\rvert_{x=0, z=0}.$$

I'll leave the calculations to you.

Answer (score 1):

The field along the $x$ axis is ${{E}_{x}}(x=0,y)=-{{\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \right)}_{x=0,y}}$ and so you must **first** compute the partial derivative and then replace $x$ by 0.

You cannot compute the derivative of a function on a point ${{x}_{0}}$ , knowing only $f({{x}_{0}})$ : $f'({{x}_{0}})={{\left( \frac{df}{\partial x} \right)}_{{{x}_{0}}}}\ne \left( \frac{df({{x}_{0}})}{\partial x} \right)=0$!

If you want to compute the electric field using the potential, you must find the function $V(x,y)$ outside the axis $x  = 0$.

Things would be different to compute ${{E}_{y}}(x=0,y)=-{{\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial y} \right)}_{x=0,y}}=-{{\left( \frac{dV(x=0,y)}{dy} \right)}_{y}}$

Answer (score 0):

You can in general obtain the field from
$$
\vec E=-\hat x\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial x}-
\hat y\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial y}- \hat z\frac{\partial V(x,y,z)}{\partial z} \tag{1}
$$
By symmetry the electric field for a point on the $\hat y$ axis only has an $\hat x$ component but you only have the $y$-dependence of $V$ since you have found this along the $\hat y$ axis only so (1) does not work.  You would need to know the dependence of $V$ on $x$ near the axis to be able to take the derivative and recover the $\hat x$ comment.

The situation would be different if the charges were identical.  Then, again by symmetry, you could argue the field only has an $\hat y$ component so knowing the $\hat y$ dependence of $V$ would be enough.